# SQL grouping ordered recordsets

Tags: mysql

I'm pulling listings from a mySQL database for a high scores table;

```
SELECT playerID, score FROM leaderboards ORDER BY score DESC
```

Often the same playerID comes up several times if they've had multiple score submissions. 
Is there a way to edit my query to only show that users highest score and ignore following ones by him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you wanna get a list of player with their highest score?

```
SELECT playerID, MAX(score) as max_score 
FROM leaderboards 
GROUP BY playerID 
ORDER BY max_score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT playerID, max(score) as max_score 
FROM leaderboards 
GROUP BY playerID
ORDER BY max_score DESC
```